# How to check how many times a number has been entered

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to solve one of the questions on a task sheet I've been received, to help me further in my understanding of C++ code from my class.

The question is (and I quote):

*Write a program that:*

- Asks the user to enter 10 numbers between 1 and 5 into an array and displays the array on screen
- Creates a second array of size 5 and fills it with zeros
- Counts how many 1s, 2s, , … 5s have been entered into the first array and stores this number in the second array.
- Displays the second array as shown in the example below.

The problem is how to go about checking how many times a number was entered. I was thinking of a `for` loop, but the way I wrote it is fundamentally incorrect, so I find myself struggling to see the mistake I am having. Perhaps I am missing something simple? Any help would be great.

Here is my (terrible) `for` loop attempt, so you can see my error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int input[10];
    const int MAX_NO = 5;
    int COUNT[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
    int count = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number for value " << i + 1 << " :";
        cin >> input[i];

        while (input[i] < 1 || input[i] > 5)
        {
            cout << "Error: Enter another number between 1 and 5: ";
            cin >> input[i];
        }
    }

    cout << endl << "You entered ";

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << input[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    // show how many times 1 number appears 

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == i)
        {
            COUNT[i]++;
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NO; i++)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << " appears " << COUNT[i]
             << " times in the input" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
COUNT[ input[i]-1 ]++;
```

in your first loop (after validation).  Once you do that, you don't need a second loop to tally up the results.

This works from the inside out by first getting what `input[i]` is, then using it to modify the `(input[i]-1)`'th location in the `COUNT` array.  If the user enters 4 on the first run of the loop, then `i == 0` and `input[i] == 4`. Since arrays are 0-based, it will increment `COUNT[input[i]-1]` which in this case is `COUNT[4-1] == COUNT[3]`.

After your initial loop runs the number of 1's will be in `COUNT[0]`, the number of 2's will be in `COUNT[1]` and so on.

Comment: I deleted my message purely because I didn't read your message properly. apologies for that it's been a long day, thank you very much after you've edited it and explained it I've better understood your logic. and yes I can see how you've done it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
//declare a constant values
int input[10];
int count = 10;  //all constant MUST be in capital letters

//second array filled with zeros
const int MAX_NO = 5;   
int COUNT[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

//ask user for 10 input values
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter a number for value " << i + 1 << " :";
    cin >> input[i];
    //check if input numbers are between 1 and 5 inclusive
    while (input[i] < 1 || input[i] > 5)
    {
        cout << "Error: Enter another number between 1 and 5: ";
        cin >> input[i];
    }
    /* show how many times 1 number appears.
    this section should be in the main loop which would enable the program to check how many times a
    number is entered so that it is stored in the second array. changed i to secondCount because this is the counting index of the second array not the first which you've called i (one of the reason you'd all zero as output when u ran your code)*/

    for (int secondCount = 1; secondCount <= MAX_NO; secondCount++)  
    {
        if (input[i] == secondCount)
        {
            COUNT[secondCount-1]+= 1;    //use minus 1 from i and increment. += 1 is the same as COUNT++
        }
    }
}

//display number entered in the first array
cout << endl << "You entered ";

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    cout << input[i] << " ";
}

cout << "\n";

//display how many times a number is entered.

for (int secondCount = 0; secondCount < MAX_NO; secondCount++)
{
    cout << secondCount + 1 << " appears " << COUNT[secondCount]
        << " times in the input" << endl;
}
cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Please enter a number for value 1 = 1
Please enter a number for value 2 = 1
Please enter a number for value 3 = 1
Please enter a number for value 4 = 2
Please enter a number for value 5 = 3
Please enter a number for value 6 = 2
Please enter a number for value 7 = 4
Please enter a number for value 8 = 4
Please enter a number for value 9 = 3
Please enter a number for value 10 = 2

You entered: 1 1 1 2 3 2 4 4 3 2 

1 appears 3 times in the input
2 appears 3 times in the input
3 appears 2 times in the input
4 appears 2 times in the input
5 appears 0 times in the input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (input[i] == i)
    {
        COUNT[i]++;
    }
}
```

Let's examine what this is doing. It starts by checking `input[1]`. (This should be `input[0]` as array indices start at 0). Then it checks if `input[1]` is equal to 1. If it is, then it increments `COUNT[1]`. 
Next, it checks `input[2]`. Then it checks if `input[2]` is equal to 2. If it is, it increments `COUNT[2]`. And so on until it has gone through `input[5]`.
Do you see the problem with this? You're only checking the first 5 inputs and only checking them against a single value.

Comment: yes i am aware of what i did wrong, i did state it in the description i just thought i'd best leave it in so people knew what i am thinking of at this moment in time in how to go about doing it, even if i know its incorrect

Comment: You stated that you knew the loop was wrong, which it was. But does this illustrate better why it is wrong? You need to check each value in the input (so loop from 0 to 9) and increment the correct place.

Comment: yeah the way you explained it is the conclusion i came too when i put break points in and followed the code as it got ran.